# Scroll to see more bars on a bar chart

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart

I have a large time series data and I re-sampled the data in hourly intervals.

I plotted a stacked bar chart using columns from the DataFrame, however due to the large dataset, it's difficult to view the bars clearly as they are cluttered together, the only way I can have it uncluttered is when I plot only a small sample of the data.

I would like to **plot the whole data** and have something like a **scroll bar that would enable me scroll to see more bars**.

For example, I want only a reasonable amount of bars visible on the figure and when there is need to view more bars, I should be able to scroll horizontally to view more bars on the figure. I would appreciate any help or suggestions on how this can be achieved.

Here is my code and the result so far:

```
node_df=df.resample('H', on='START_TIMESTAMP').NODES_USED.sum()
node_df=pd.DataFrame(node_df,columns=['NODES_USED'])
node_df['UNUSED_NODES']=49152-node_df['NODES_USED']
node_df.tail(20).plot.bar(stacked=True, figsize=(15,12))
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.ylabel('Nodes')
plt.legend(loc='upper right')
plt.show()
```

[image: Bar Chart]